# Converting mysql from linux to windows server

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a MySQL database running on a Linux (Ubuntu) server.
We are thinking of moving this database to a Windows 2008 R2 server (our IT-team's Linux knowledge isn't that good).

I have a couple of questions:

1. Is there a difference in performance (running MySQL) between these two servers?
2. Are there some big drawbacks running MySQL on Windows?
3. Do we have to think of something special when moving from Linux to Windows.

Comment: Don't use any MySQL version earlier than 5.5 and you should be fine performance wise. http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/5.5/mysql-55-faster-on-windows.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1,2 : In terms of performance there’s not a huge difference between the two servers. Linux reportedly performs faster because Windows (as usual) attempts to offer an ‘all in one’ package instead of the extendable Linux implementation. You’ll generally not notice a difference but if performance is of utmost importance to you then maybe this will influence your decision.

3:Table names and databases are case insensitive in Windows.and You Should do a mysqldump of everything while converting linux to windows.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I warn about is the use of constraints

Table names and databases are case sensitive in Linux

Table names and databases are case insensitive in Windows.

This is not a problem if you used only lower case letters in Linux. A mysqldump should port to Windows just fine.

If you have any tables whose constraints have mixed upper and lower letters, you need to mysqldump just the schema (using `--no-data`), edit the schema dump's constraints to all lower case, load the mysqldump of the schema into Windows mysql and loa the data separately.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for inconsistencies due to case sensitivity in your code. MySQL is case sensitive when run on a Linux server (OS dependant) but case insensitive on Windows. This could cause a lot of headaches depending.